# What are the default values for unmentioned facets in an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

What are the default values for facets and restrictions in an XSD, if they are not otherwise specified?

For example, several places mention that `minoccurs` = 1 and `maxoccurs` = 1, if they are not otherwise specified - but what about the other facets? Or don't they have defaults?:

```
minExclusive    
minInclusive    
maxExclusive    
maxInclusive    
totalDigits 
fractionDigits  
length  
minLength   
maxLength   
enumeration 
whiteSpace
pattern
usage
```

Comment: Have you seen the [Schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes)?

Comment: yes, I didn't see anything in there about the default values. I looked here (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) and in the wikibooks on XSD files, amongst various google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes) you cannot specify both `minExclusive` and `minInclusive` together, and similarly `maxExclusive` and `maxInclusive` - the defaults vary by datatype, so for some of the main types:

> **float** is patterned after the IEEE single-precision 32-bit floating point type [IEEE 754-1985]. The basic ·value space· of float consists of the values m × 2^e, where m is an integer whose absolute value is less than 2^24, and e is an integer between -149 and 104, inclusive
>
> The **double** datatype is patterned after the IEEE double-precision 64-bit floating point type [IEEE 754-1985]. The basic ·value space· of double consists of the values m × 2^e, where m is an integer whose absolute value is less than 2^53, and e is an integer between -1075 and 970, inclusive.
>
> **dateTime** values may be viewed as objects with integer-valued year, month, day, hour and minute properties, a decimal-valued second property, and a boolean timezoned property. Each such object also has one decimal-valued method or computed property, timeOnTimeline, whose value is always a decimal number; the values are dimensioned in seconds, the integer 0 is 0001-01-01T00:00:00 and the value of timeOnTimeline for other dateTime values is computed using the Gregorian algorithm as modified for leap-seconds. The timeOnTimeline values form two related "timelines", one for timezoned values and one for non-timezoned values. Each timeline is a copy of the ·value space· of decimal, with integers given units of seconds.

i.e minInclusive is 1/1/0001 0:00:00

> **time** represents an instant of time that recurs every day. The ·value space· of time is the space of time of day values as defined in § 5.3 of [ISO 8601]. Specifically, it is a set of zero-duration daily time instances.

i.e minInclusive is 0:00:00 and maxExclusive is 24:00:00

> **integer** is ·derived· from decimal by fixing the value of ·fractionDigits· to be 0and disallowing the trailing decimal point. This results in the standard mathematical concept of the integer numbers. The ·value space· of integer is the infinite set {...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...}.

i.e. fractionDigits is only ever 0

> **nonPositiveInteger** is ·derived· from integer by setting the value of ·maxInclusive· to be 0. This results in the standard mathematical concept of the non-positive integers. The ·value space· of nonPositiveInteger is the infinite set {...,-2,-1,0}.

i.e. fractionDigits is only ever 0, and maxInclusive is 0

> **long** is ·derived· from integer by setting the value of ·maxInclusive· to be 9223372036854775807 and ·minInclusive· to be -9223372036854775808.
>
> **int** is ·derived· from long by setting the value of ·maxInclusive· to be 2147483647 and ·minInclusive· to be -2147483648.
>
> **short** is ·derived· from int by setting the value of ·maxInclusive· to be 32767 and ·minInclusive· to be -32768
>
> **byte** is ·derived· from short by setting the value of ·maxInclusive· to be 127 and ·minInclusive· to be -128

Comment: OK, thanks for that, that makes sense for most simple types. What about custom types? Usage especially doesn't depend on the type as far as I can see - so is there a default for that?

Comment: `usage` is not a [constraining facet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-facets)

Comment: OK, interesting. Still, whatever it is, does it have a default?

Comment: "usage" in fact isn't an allowable attribute, nor element, for that version of the schema ([according to the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dtd-for-datatypeDefs))